# How to create a batch program that will validate if date format entered is correct

Tags: windows, validation, date, batch-file, cmd

I need some help guys. I am currently doing a batch program that asks for a date in `MM-DD-YYYY` format (the dashes "-" are included in the user input) then that date will be added to the filenames of all text files in a folder. That part was easy for me. What I don't know how to do is to make a validation in the program wherein the user will only be allowed to input a valid date (no letters) and only limited to 8 characters (since a date only has 8 numbers).

I don't know if this is possible in a batch program, but another thing I would like to do is that when the program prompts the user for a date, the message will be displayed like the following:

```
`Enter Report Date: MM/DD/YYYY`
```

Wherein the MMDDYYYY is already an input field which is editable. The slashes "/" are displayed by default but not editable; it will only serve as separators for the month, day, and year user input. This will eliminate the need to include dashes "-" in the user input (in my current program).

After the user has inputted the date and the program has validated that the format is correct, the date inputted will be added into the filenames of all text files (as a suffix) stored in a folder. But the format of the date to be added into the filenames will be `MM-DD-YYYY` which means the slashes "/" will not be included (since it's not allowed in filenames) and will be replaced with dashes "-". Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2):

Check with the `date` function, if your date is valid:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "sdate=%date%"

SET "ndate=07/22/2013"
SET "ndate=%ndate:/=-%"
ECHO %ndate%|DATE >NUL 2>&1 && ECHO "%ndate%" is a valid DATE || ECHO "%ndate%" is NOT a valid DATE
SET "ndate=17-22-2013"
SET "ndate=%ndate:/=-%"
ECHO %ndate%|DATE >NUL 2>&1 && ECHO "%ndate%" is a valid DATE || ECHO "%ndate%" is NOT a valid DATE
SET "date=%sdate%"
PAUSE
```

..output is:

```
"07-22-2013" is a valid DATE
"17-22-2013" is NOT a valid DATE
```

Comment: Thanks. The program is good, but it doesn't ask the user to input a date and make further validations on it. For example, if the user will input 02/29/2013, the program should display a message that it's an invalid date since the year 2013 is not a leap year. Also, if the user will input alpha characters, the program should not allow it and only accept numeric values.

Comment: this is unfortunately not the Java corner :(